# Parametrize the style="margin-top:Xem" to set any X

Tags: html

I want to build  by a plainText that is read from a file.
That file has that look:

```
Line1

Line3
```

Line2 is totally empty, even without a space.
The html file then looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC><html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>#editor { white-space: pre; }</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: 'Segoe Print'; font-size:14pt">

<p id='editor', style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px">Line1</p>
<p id='editor', style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px"></p>
<p id='editor', style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px">Line3</p>

</body></html>
```

The code lines with "p id=..." are important. The middle line of them is ignored, so that there are only two lines shown. Thats because there is no text before the closing /p, right? I could of course enter a " " (space), but thats a dirty solution...

I've found a half-way solution by inserting "margin-top:Xem" instead of "margin-top:0px" in the lower line. X is "1". The question now is:

How can i put any other value, e.g. 4, for X when the program figured out that there are 4 empty lines?

EDIT: Here is what I tried. Nothing changed...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC><html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>p.editor { white-space: pre; min-height:1em; }</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: 'Segoe Print'; font-size:14pt">

<p class='editor' style=" margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0px;">Line1</p>
<p class='editor' style=" margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0px;"></p>
<p class='editor' style=" margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0px;">Line3</p>

</body></html>
```

Comment: `id='editor',` same id for 3 elements + extra comma

Comment: What do you mean by this? I don't understand.

Comment: 1) id should be unique 2) you need to remove that comma, it's incorrect syntax

Comment: Yes okay but how is this related to my question?

Comment: That's the first thing you need to fix in your code.

Comment: @mishik - Not just _should_ be unique, _must_ be unique.

Comment: Oh I just tested it in phase5. I put id="editor" after body and before style, it changed the behaviour. Is this now the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

1. IDs must be [unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Change those to use classes instead.
2. You only need spaces to separate element attributes, not commas.
3. You should use CSS rather than inline styling.

If you want a a `p` element to display without any text included, simply give it a minimum height.

```html
<p class="editor">Line 1</p>
<p class="editor"></p>
<p class="editor">Line 3</p>
```

```css
p.editor {
    white-space: pre;
    margin:0;
    min-height:16px;
}
```

By default `p` elements default to the height of the content within. With no content, there is simply no height. Specifying a minimum height means that the empty `p` element will always have some height regardless of whether it has content or not.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TG69U/1).

If you want the empty line to be copy-able, however, you'll need to modify the HTML itself to use a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (`&nbsp;`) instead of leaving your elements empty:

```html
<p class="editor">Line 1</p>
<p class="editor">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="editor">Line 3</p>
```

With this you wouldn't need the extra minimum height as the non-breaking space adheres to the font size of the element.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TG69U/2/).

Comment: I fiddled around a bit. In my example, where do I have to place the    

      p.editor {
        min-height:1em;
        margin:0;
      }

?

Comment: Ah I guess in between the style part

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>h1 { white-space: pre; min-height:1em; font-family: arial;
    font-size:8pt; color:green; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:0px}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<h1>Line1</h1>
<h1></h1>
<h1>Line3</h1>

</body></html>
```

Inserting that in Phase, it works.
Setting that to a QTextBrowser, it does not. But that's another question